# Can't GetObject but policy says I should be able to. (AWS S3)

Tags: security, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have the following policy on my bucket:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "PolicyID",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Download",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Upload",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

And some file `SomeFile.txt` with *no* individual permissions and *no* owner. However, despite the policy, if I attempt to Get the object anonymously, I have no luck. I really don't know what to do about this. I suspect the lack of owner is the problem, but I'm truthfully lost.

Also, only objects uploaded through my python service suffer this issue. Those uploaded online are fine.

Comment: Is the upload working? and do you get any error while get object?

Comment: The upload works, when I get object I get Access Denied. I'm going to try everything another time to get specifics.

Comment: How do you access the file? From browser or command line?

Comment: Just checked again, Access Denied on Get, no problem on Put. I access the file from a browser and from a Lambda service for Get. For Put I use an authenticated Python service (although without explicit permissions for this bucket)

Comment: Are you accessing  the object programmatically? or from the browser?

Comment: Just added that to my previous comment

Comment: Oh I should add that any files I upload directly through the AWS S3 web interface have no problems, its only the python uploaded files that are giving me issue.

Comment: Can you paste the Python code used for uploading the files?

Comment: Ok sure thing. One sec

Comment: Its not the whole program but what I believe to be the relevant code @error2007s: http://pastebin.com/fCE1F9Ut

Comment: There is a possibility that there is issue in Lambda having access to S3 bucket uploaded files. Are you able to access files from browser if that file is uploaded through Python ?

Comment: No in fact I cant even add permissions to files uploaded through python

Comment: When the file is uploaded through python what name is the file saved by can you paste the name of the any file that was uploaded through python boto3?

Comment: According to the Boto3 S3 upload_file documentation, you should upload your upload like this: "upload_file(Filename, Bucket, Key, ExtraArgs=None, Callback=None, Config=None)"

Comment: I have to go now but thank you for your help, I think its a good idea to look through the boto3 docs